# Source for this midrash?

Tags: midrash

Can someone quote where this midrash is found- there was a man who came to a rabbi and asked him to come live in his city and he’ll give him all the money, and the rabbi basically roasted the city and said I’ll never live with you apikorsim

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.9

Comment: @אילפא yes that’s it, thank you! Wanna put it as an answer and I’ll mark it?

Comment: He didn't call them "Apikorsim", nor "roast" them. He just said living in a place of Torah was worth all the money in the world, for him.

Comment: @Shalom well that’s clearly why I’m looking for the midrash, I’m a little iffy on the details